# c# textbox decimal formatting

Tags: c#, formatting, decimal

I want my text boxes which are binded to money (SqlServer) entity fields, to show just two decimal places instead of four places.

I use DevExpress `textEdit` and `CalcEdit` boxes with the following display and edit format : `"#,##0.00#;(#,##0.00#)";` But I always get four decimal places (zeros).

I use the same format string in Janus Grid, the values get display correctly.

Any Idea, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I would highly recommend using the built-in format strings wherever possible, such as `N2`.

```
string s = number.ToString("N2");
```

Use John Sheehan's [.NET Format String Quick Reference](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/msnet-formatting-strings.pdf) Cheat Sheet when in doubt. It has all the info you need about formatting numbers and dates in .NET.

DevExpress controls usually require you to also specify what you are formatting (e.g. a number, date etc.):

```
calcEdit.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Numeric;
calcEdit.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "N2";
```

If the format type isn't specified, the format string won't be applied.

With TextEdit you should specify a Mask instead.

```
textEdit.Properties.Mask.MaskType = MaskType.Numeric;
textEdit.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "N2";
```

Comment: Tried this, but no success. Thanks

Comment: No way to get only two decimals, using the designer.
Which event shout I use to format the text of the textboxes.

When I DoubleClick on a Grid Row ( numeric columns well formatted), I show the same data on a form with textboxes (showing trailing four zeros in the numeric textboxes).

Comment: Try specifying a mask instead. See my updated answer. If you're using a BindingSource to display data in the text edits, specify the format string on the binding instead of the control.

Comment: This is the only solution to my problem:             var currencyBinding = new Binding
            ("Text", entityBindingSource, "Amount");

            currencyBinding.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(DecimalToCurrencyString);
            txbAmount.DataBindings.Add(currencyBinding); // Thnak you for your suggestion.

Comment: In one the constructor overloads of Binding (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158047.aspx) you can specify the format string directly. Does this not work? I find it hard to believe that the Mask solution doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that constructor, it works. But the Mask Solution didn't.

Comment: The link (to John Sheehan's Cheat Sheets) is (effectively) broken. It asks for login information and entering this results in "Request denied. You do not have permission to access this page.".

Comment: John Sheehan's Cheat Sheets is also at devcheatsheet.com/cheatsheet/102, but the link from there is also (effectively) broken.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

for example you have a variable named amount. then format it like this,

```
amount.ToString("###,###.00");
```

It will give you amount in two decimal places.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My TextBoxes are binded to an entity with numeric fields, should I format the textboxes when first the data is loaded, then reformat each time a textbox value has changed?

Answer (score 3):

Try `#,##0.00` -- you shouldn't need the trailing "#".

Answer (score 0):

I usually just write the new formatted value back into the text box after it has been validated.  So if its a decimal to the thousandths then in the validated event handler I write the value back into the text after its been parsed to a float like this.  this.textbox1.Text = speed.ToString("N3").